# Populate in mongoose not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the model for course and topic, I want to populate topic in course with the help of mongoose. When we call API I want a joint result of course and topic.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let courseSchema = new Schema({
  course_id: {
    type: Number
  },
  course_title: {
    type: String
  },
  course_description: {
    type: String
  },
  course_duration:{
    type: Number
  },
  topic:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Topic"
  }
}, {
    collection: "courses"
  })

  let topicSchema = new Schema({
    topic_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    topic_title: {
        type: String
    },
    topic_description: {
        type: String
    }               
}
    ,{
        collection: "topics"
    })

const Topic = mongoose.model("Topic", topicSchema)
const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema)
module.exports = { Topic, Course };
```

This is API for GET, and I use populate as well but not able to get the joint result of course and topic.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
express = require('express'),
router = express.Router();
var { Topic, Course }= require('../models/Course')
    router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
      Course.find().populate('topic').exec((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          return next(error)
        } else {
          res.json(data)
        }
      })
    })
```

I want output like this:

```
{
        "_id": "5fea9d7cd6651122e04ce5ed",
        "course_id": 2,
        "course_title": "GOlang",
        "course_description": "google ",
        "course_duration": 11,
        "topic_id": 3,
        "topic_title": "hoisting",
        "topic_description": "variable and function",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whay did you do that ?

```
   router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Course.find().populate('topic').exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

and not this instead ?

```
   router.get('/',(req, res) => {
  Course.find().populate('topic').exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Okay, but it is the same in implementation. I will make those changes According to your suggestion.

Comment: ok, because I've never seen this syntax! When you do that find it working? must already test if by doing that find it works! then we can determine if it is because of populate or because of a road or something else